# In what order should the code be interpreted?

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to interpret this SQL code but no matter how much I try I don't get the right output. Tables are:

```
  T1     T2
C1 C2   C1 C2
A  1    A  4
A  2    A  2
B  2    B  2
C  1    D  5
```

Am I reading the code from the wrong way (up -> down)? 
The SELECT DISTINCT, doesn't this mean that I should leave out one of the rows of each table that are duplicates?

Should I start with joining the tables by the condition T1.C1=T2.C1?

My own output is:

```
A 1 A 4
A 2 A 2
B 2 B 2
```

The right output is:

```
A 2 A 2
A 2 A 4
B 2 B 2
```

The code in question:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.C1, T1.C2, T2.C1, T2.C2
FROM T1
JOIN T2 ON T1.C1 = T2.C1
WHERE T1.C2 IN (2, 4)
```

Comment: It will help if you show us the contents of the two tables. Please [edit] your question,

Comment: `Distinct` is going to act last here. That says "After all the results of the `FROM/JOIN` and the `WHERE` clause are applied take the result set and return only distinct rows". Your output is incorrect, not because of the order of operations, but rather that you ignored the filter on `T1.C2` which can onnly hold values `2` and `4`. So your first row can't be in the output as `t1.C2` is equal to `1`. It's difficult to expand on the rest of this without seeing the data for `t1` and `t2`.

Comment: I see! Still, with this filter (2,4) the first row of T1 is removed and I'm then left with two rows from T1 joined with three rows of T2 in order 4 2 2 instead of 2 4 2.

Comment: @Michelangelo Well... that's another spot that is wrong. When you join T1 and T2 on `C1` colmn, for your `T1` row `A, 2` you will join to TWO records in `T2`. So you will have `A,2,A,2` AND `A,2,A,4` in your output, both of which survive your `WHERE` predicate. And they are also distinct so they survive through your aggregation as well. Consider: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nfAje9KstJRjHSHHAeBGUm/0

Comment: @JNevill I see! But why is the A 2 over the A 4 row in T2?

Comment: It's not over it. It's joined to it. They both share an "a" in the C1 column upon which they are joined.

Comment: @JNevill So the output could also be the reverse order between these two in T2?

Comment: Order has nothing to do with this. There is no ordering to records in a table as they are written to disk. Ordering is only determined/applied using an ORDER BY clause in a SQL statement when a result set for a query is being created.

Comment: @JNevill Alright! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

SQL statement flow is a little strange until you get used to it.

First, you name the source of data, in your case the virtual table made with this.

```
FROM T1
JOIN T2 ON T1.C1 = T2.C1
```

Next, you filter the source of data.

```
WHERE T1.C2 IN (2, 4)
```

Next, you choose the columns you want in your output result set:

```
SELECT T1.C1, T1.C2, T2.C1, T2.C2
```

Next, you aggregate the data by inserting the `DISTINCT` clause, or with a `GROUP BY` clause.

Next you sort it with an `ORDER BY` clause. You don't have one. That's OK.

That's the logical structure of a SQL query like yours. But keep in mind that MySQL and other SQL table servers have thousands of programmer years dedicated to optimizing this stuff.